# Check Array is Symmetric Tree or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of `string` and I want to check is it a Symmetric Tree or not.

Array will represent a binary tree, and determine if the tree is symmetric (a mirror image of itself). The array will be implemented similar to how a binary heap is implemented, except the tree may not be complete and `NULL` nodes on any level of the tree will be represented with a `#`.

For example: if `strArr` is `["1", "2", "2", "3", "#", "#", "3"]` then this tree looks like the following:

[image]

For the input above, your program should return the string `true` because the binary tree is symmetric.

**Examples**

```
Input: ["4", "3", "4"]
Output: false

Input: ["10", "2", "2", "#", "1", "1", "#"]
Output: true
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the input is a valid tree, i.e., `strArr.length` is one less than a power of 2

```
function isSymmetric(strArr) {
  for (let level = 0; (2 ** (level + 1)) - 1 <= strArr.length; level++) {
    let row = strArr.slice((2 ** level) - 1, (2 ** (level + 1) - 1));
    if (JSON.stringify(row) !== JSON.stringify(row.reverse())) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

let testArr = ["10", "2", "2", "#", "1", "1", "#"];
console.log(isSymmetric(testArr))
```

Answer (score -1):

## algorithm used

`araay = ["10" , "2", "2", "#", "1", "1", "#"]`
lets break this into each step

```
step 1 = ["10"]
step 2 = [ "2", "2" ]
step 3 = ["#", "1", "1", "#"]
```

check mirror for each step other than first step

lets take step 3 .
`step 3 = ["#", "1", "1", "#"]`
break this into 2  array from middle

```
step 3 1 = ["#", "1" ]
step 3 2 = ["1", "#"]
```

Now reverse step 3 2

```
step 3 2 = ["1", "#"]
```

now check if step 3 2 is equal to step 3 1

Do the above thing for each step

if all are mirror then binary tree is  mirror

```js
const Input = ["10" , "2", "2", "#", "1", "1", "#"];
function isEqual(a,b)
{
  // if length is not equal
  if(a.length!=b.length)
   return false;
  else
  {
  // comapring each element of array
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   if(a[i] !== b[i]){
    return false;
   }
    return true;
  }
}

// Response 
let symetric = true ;
let stepSymetric = true ;
let mirror = true ;
// length of input 
const length = Input.length ;
// const length = 31 ;

// lets create binary tree from it

const totalSteps =
      Math.log(length + 1)/Math.log(2) ;

// check for symetric binary tree
function checkInt(n) { return parseInt(n) === n };
 symetric = checkInt(totalSteps);

//now check for mirror
let goneArrayLength = 0 ;
for (let i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) { 
  const cStep = Math.pow(2,i);
  
  const stepArray = [];
  // console.log(goneArrayLength);
  
  // now update the step array 
  const start = goneArrayLength ;
  const end =  goneArrayLength + cStep ;
  
  for (let j = start; j < end; j++) {
    stepArray.push(Input[j])
  }
  
  console.log(stepArray);
  // Now we have each step lets find they are mirror image or not
  // check for even length
  if(stepArray.length%2 !== 0 && i !== 0){
    stepSymetric = false ;
  }
  const partitation = stepArray.length / 2 ;
  const leftArray = stepArray.slice(0,partitation);
  const rightArray = stepArray.slice(partitation , partitation * 2);
  // console.log("leftArray");
  // console.log(leftArray);
  // console.log("rightArray");
  // console.log(rightArray);
  function mirrorCheck (){
    let check = false;
    if(cStep === 1){
      return true ;
    }
    let array1 = leftArray;
    let array2 = rightArray.reverse();
    // console.log("first");
    // console.log(array1);
    // console.log("second");
    // console.log(array2);
   let equal = isEqual(array1 , array2)
   // console.log(equal);
    check = true ;
    if(!equal){
      // console.log("Noooooooooooooooo")
      check = false ;
    }
    
    return check;
  }
  let mirrorC = mirrorCheck();
  
  if(!mirrorC){
    mirror = false;
  }
  goneArrayLength = goneArrayLength + cStep ;
}
console.log(mirror + " " + symetric + " " + stepSymetric )

if(mirror && symetric && stepSymetric ){
  console.log("Mirror Image");
  
}
else{
  console.log("Not mirror image")
}
// console.log(isSymetric);
// console.log(totalSteps);
```